# realtime calculation with javascript inside foreach code

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, laravel

Now im doing laravel project for implement function realtime calculate result with javascipt. i combine `<table>` and `foreach()` code. here is my table design

[image]

- every person have different list items
- we can input number on "PRICE" and "Dicounst(%)" column
- Realtime calculation will place on each "result place", bottom "grant total price", bottom "grant total Discount" and "grant total result price"

here is the html code

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>price</th>
            <th>Discount (%)</th>
            <th>result price</th> 
        </tr>
    </thead> 

    <tbody> 
        <!-- Ussy Sulistiawaty -->
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">Ussy Sulistiawaty</td>
            <td>top video</td>
            <td><input class="profile-3-price-0" type="number" name="price[xx]" ></td>
            <td><input class="profile-3-discount-0" type="number" name="discount[xx]" ></td>
            <td><span id="profile-3-result-0"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <td>top post</td>
            <td><input class="profile-3-price-1" type="number" name="price[xx]" ></td>
            <td><input class="profile-3-discount-1" type="number" name="discount[xx]" ></td>
            <td><span id="profile-3-result-1"></span></td>
        </tr>

        <!-- Andrea Dian Bimo -->
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3">Andrea Dian Bimo</td>
            <td>top Post</td>
            <td><input class="profile-10-price-0" type="number" name="price[xx]" ></td>
            <td><input class="profile-10-discount-0" type="number" name="discount[xx]" ></td>
            <td><span id="profile-10-result-0"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <td>top video</td>
            <td><input class="profile-10-price-1" type="number" name="price[xx]" ></td>
            <td><input class="profile-10-discount-1" type="number" name="discount[xx]" ></td>
            <td><span id="profile-10-result-1"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <td>top story</td>
            <td><input class="profile-10-price-2" type="number" name="price[xx]" ></td>
            <td><input class="profile-10-discount-2" type="number" name="discount[xx]" ></td>
            <td><span id="profile-10-result-2"></span></td>
        </tr>

        <!-- Shandy Aulia -->
        <tr>
            <td>Shandy Aulia</td>
            <td>top video</td>
            <td><input class="profile-13-price-0" type="number" name="price[xx]" ></td>
            <td><input class="profile-13-discount-0" type="number" name="discount[xx]" ></td>
            <td><span id="profile-13-result-0"></span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Grand Total</th>
            <th> <span id="totalprice"></span> </th>
            <th> <span id="totaldiscount"></span> </th>
            <th> <span id="totalresultprice"></span></th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

i define class name with this

- `class="profile-3-price-0"`  is `profile-{{user->id}}-price{{ $array_key }}`
- `class="profile-3-discount-0"`  is `profile-{{user->id}}-discount{{ $array_key }}`
- `class="profile-3-result-0"`  is `profile-{{user->id}}-result{{ $array_key }}`

realtime calculate will set on this

- `profile-{{user->id}}-result{{ $array_key }}`, formula is `profile-{{user->id}}-price{{ $array_key }}` x `profile-{{user->id}}-discount{{ $array_key }}`
- `<span id="totalprice"></span>` will display sum for all "price"
- `<span id="totaldiscount"></span>` will display result sum for all "discount"
- `<span id="totalresultprice"></span>` will display result sum for all "result price"

i still not able to do that with indexing for class name or id name. before this, i tried this script.

```
 $("tbody").on("input", function() {

        const totalinternalcost = $(".internalCost").map(function(i, input) {
            const val = input.value && !isNaN(input.value) ? +input.value : 0;
            $(input).closest("tr").find("td").eq(4).text(val)
            return val;
        }).get().reduce((acc, cur) => { acc += cur; return acc; }, 0)
        $("#totalinternalcost").text(totalinternalcost);


        const totalEach = $(".internalCost").map(function(i, input) {
            const internalCost = input.value && !isNaN(input.value) ? +input.value : 0;
            let  grossProfit = $(input).closest("td").next().find("input").val();
            grossProfit = grossProfit && !isNaN(grossProfit) ? +grossProfit : 0;
            const val = (internalCost - internalCost * (grossProfit/100))
            $(input).closest("tr").find("td").eq(4).text(val.toFixed(2))
            return val;
        }).get().reduce((acc, cur) => { acc += cur; return acc; }, 0)

        $("#totalcostperunit").text(totalEach.toFixed(2))

        const totalgrossprofit = $(".grossProfit").map(function(i, input) {
            return input.value && !isNaN(input.value) ? +input.value : 0;
        }).get().reduce((acc, cur) => {
            acc += cur;
            return acc;
        }, 0)
        $("#totalgrossprofit").text(totalgrossprofit);

    });
```

but that script not work properly. because it read column number. if you see, my table use code `rowspan`. so the script not work.  i understand the concept index for class name and id name. but i still confuse, how to implement use javascript code.

please help how to solve this.

Comment: do someone can help me for this ?